# How to keep map key order in json when I return object from @RestControler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

I want to keep map entries order thus I've added following bean into context:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS, true);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

Also I have following controller:

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
@GetMapping(value = "/mapping", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<MappingDTO> getMapping(HttpServletRequest request) {
    MappingDTO mappingDTO = mappingService.getMapping();
    String str = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mappingDTO); // added this line for test perpose
    return ResponseEntity.ok(mappingDTO);
}
```

dto:

```
public class MappingDTO {
    private String id;
    private Map<String, List<MappingEntry>> entries;
    ...
```

`str` variable contains correct json  with correct order but when I execute Get request - order is broken.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper

Comment: @PillHead, excuse me?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a LinkedHashMap to store your values, it will keep the insertion order:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    class Dto {
        private Map<String, List<Integer>> entries = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        public Dto() {
            final List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
            l1.add(2);
            l1.add(1);
            entries.put("A", l1);
            final List<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
            l2.add(4);
            l2.add(6);
            entries.put("C", l2);
            final List<Integer> l3 = new ArrayList<>();
            l3.add(5);
            l3.add(3);
            entries.put("B", l3);
        }

        public Map<String, List<Integer>> getEntries() {
            return entries;
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("json")
    public ResponseEntity<Dto> getJson() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new Dto());
    }
}
```

The request to `/json` will result in `{"entries":{"A":[2,1],"C":[4,6],"B":[5,3]}}`, but if you use regular `Map`, the result will be `{"entries":{"A":[2,1],"B":[5,3],"C":[4,6]}}`

This assumes you would like to keep the **insertion** order (it's not clear from your question). If, however, you prefer to have the map being sorted by keys, use `TreeMap` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want keys sorted lexicographically, add

```
spring.jackson.serialization.order-map-entries-by-keys=true
```

to the `application.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following link

[ObjectMapper configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper)

It provides instructions on how to configure the default mapper or use a custom mapper.

> If you want to replace the default ObjectMapper completely, either
>   define a @Bean of that type and mark it as @Primary...

Therefore I think you are missing the @Primary annotation

Comment: Actually I tried this annotation but result the same. In debug I see that spring uses the same mapper, but result - different

Comment: are there any other definitions of ObjectMapper in your codebase that are being used instead?

Comment: No, I don't have another definitions of ObjectMapper. At least explicitly

Comment: the other option suggested by the link is to set an environment variable spring.jackson.serialization.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS=true

Comment: Actually my question is mistaken. It is just google chrome json preview sorts json keys in alphabet order