# Dynamically Sort JSON output order

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot app that is reading from a CSV file and converting the results to POJO objects. However the CSV header ordering is important. Meaning there are rows that contain data associated to a particular month. My client wants the JSON order to reflect the header order from the CSV. The issue is that my JSON order is picking up the order that is applied in my model not from the header order. Is there a way to dynamically reorder the model so it reflects the csv order?

CSV Order:

```
Base,Jun,May,Apr,Mar,Feb,Jan,Dec,Nov,Oct,Sep,Aug,Jul
```

Model:

```
pricate int base;
private String jan;
private String feb;
private String mar;
private String apr;
private String may:
private String jun;
private String jul;
private String aug;
private String sep;
private String oct;
private String nov;
private String dec;


// Typical Getters and Setters here
```

Curent Json Order:

```
data:[{
    base:,
    jan :,
    feb :,
    mar :,
    apr :,
    may :,
    jun :,
    jul :,
    aug :,
    sep :,
    oct :,
    nov :,
    dec :
}]
```

Expected JSON Output:

```
data:[{
    base :,     
    jun :,
    may :,
    apr :,
    mar :,
    feb :,
    jan :,
    dec :,
    nov :,
    oct :,
    sep :,
    aug :,
    jul :
}]
```

NOTE: This order will change each month, meaning the left most month in the csv will be 1 month ahead of current month and this should be represented as the first month below base on the JSON output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [chelmertz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49879/chelmertz) noted in [another anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61731779/4494577) one should not depend on JSON object key order in their implementations - it might (and will sonner or later) cause trouble. Try to talk your client out of this. If the order really matters - maybe use a different representation (or maybe even format different than JSON - why not CSV for example?).

If you still want to achieve this you could change your POJO to an ordered map (e.g. LinkedHashMap) like in [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47928857/4494577):

> Just use a LinkedHashMap to store your values, it will keep the insertion order:
>
> ```
> @RestController
> public class TestController {
>     class Dto {
>         private Map<String, List<Integer>> entries = new LinkedHashMap<>();
>
>         public Dto() {
>             final List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
>             l1.add(2);
>             l1.add(1);
>             entries.put("A", l1);
>             final List<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
>             l2.add(4);
>             l2.add(6);
>             entries.put("C", l2);
>             final List<Integer> l3 = new ArrayList<>();
>             l3.add(5);
>             l3.add(3);
>             entries.put("B", l3);
>         }
>
>         public Map<String, List<Integer>> getEntries() {
>             return entries;
>         }
>     }
>
>     @GetMapping("json")
>     public ResponseEntity<Dto> getJson() {
>         return ResponseEntity.ok(new Dto());
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The request to `/json` will result in `{"entries":{"A":[2,1],"C":[4,6],"B":[5,3]}}`, but if you use regular `Map`, the result will be `{"entries":{"A":[2,1],"B":[5,3],"C":[4,6]}}`
>
> This assumes you would like to keep the **insertion** order (it's not clear from your question). If, however, you prefer to have the map being sorted by keys, use `TreeMap` instead.
>
> -- [How to keep map key order in json when I return object from @RestControler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47926641/how-to-keep-map-key-order-in-json-when-i-return-object-from-restcontroler#answer-47928857)

Comment: Grouping values as lists by keys also allows for lists of different lengths (which maybe is not too interesting in this case..) +1

Comment: @jannis I like this approach. Let me see what I can do. Essentially they need the objects mapped to the proper keys so their fronted can read in the values through a basic iterator and not have to perform any logic to match months to values on the fly. Upon testing and validation I will circle back and mark as answer if applicable.

Answer (score 2):

The JSON spec says objects are unordered, so relying on implementation details is very fragile.

> An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value
> pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number,
> boolean, null, object, or array.
>
> An array is an ordered sequence of zero or more values.
>
> -- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-1

Instead you could represent ordered values (such as indexed columns representing your CSV) with arrays. There are multiple representations, but this is valid and uses less space (no repetition of headers):

```json
{
  "headers": [
    "base",
    "jan",
    "feb",
    "mar",
    "apr",
    "may",
    "jun",
    "jul",
    "aug",
    "sep",
    "oct",
    "nov",
    "dec"
  ],
  "data": [
    [ 
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1"
    ],
    [    
      "2",
      "2",
      "2",
      "2",
      "2",
      "2",
      "2",
      "2",
      "2",
      "2",
      "2",
      "2",
      "2"
    ]
  ]
}
```